# Not certain why a comparison between a date and an array isn't finding a match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I have the following html code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
        .dp-highlight .ui-state-default {
            background: #484;
            color: #FFF;
        }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var gigDates;
    </script>

    <script>
        window.onload = getGigDates();
        function getGigDates(){
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(retDates).getDates(date);
        }

        function retDates(gigDatesTwo){
            console.log("Returning the dates needed:  " +gigDatesTwo)
            gigDates = gigDatesTwo;
        }

        $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                onSelect: function(date) {updDate(date);},
                selectWeek: true,
                inline: true,
                startDate: '01/01/2000',
                firstDay: 1,
                beforeShowDay : available,
            });
        });


        function available(date) {
            console.log("From the Spread sheet:  " +gigDates);
            var dmy = (date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
            console.log(dmy+' : '+($.inArray(dmy, gigDates)));
            if ($.inArray(dmy, gigDates) != -1) {
                return [true, "","Available"];
            } else {
                return [false,"","unAvailable"];
            }
        }

        function updDate(date){
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myReturnFunction).updDate(date);
        }

        function myReturnFunction(whatGotReturned){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = whatGotReturned;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" onchange="updDate()"></p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
</body>
```

The function getGigDates returns the following:

> ["5/12/2014","6/14/2014","6/6/2014","6/13/2014","6/17/2014","5/30/2014","6/3/2014","6/4/2014","6/18/2014","6/18/2014","6/20/2014","6/25/2014","6/19/2014","6/13/2014","6/27/2014","7/4/2014","7/1/2014","7/6/2014",]

But when the function "available" compares dmy to gigDates for 7/4/2014 it returns a -1.

Edit:  Here is part of the console output for one entry:

> From the Spread sheet:  ["5/12/2014","6/14/2014","6/6/2014","6/13/2014","6/17/2014","5/30/2014","6/3/2014","6/4/2014","6/18/2014","6/18/2014","6/20/2014","6/25/2014","6/19/2014","6/13/2014","6/27/2014","7/4/2014","7/1/2014","7/6/2014",]
>   6/14/2014 : -1

Do I have either of the variables dmy or gigDates formatted incorrectly?

Loren

edit Google script:

```
function getDates(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AnDrS3YbyWoLdC15aktnMTluUkQ3dWhNTFlyQXBPOFE");
  var list = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var values = list.getRange(1,5,ss.getLastRow(),5).getValues();

  var gigDates;

  gigDates= "[";
  for (var i in values){
    if (values[i][0]!=""){
      if (values[i][0] != "Gig Date"){
        var ssDate = Utilities.formatDate(values[i][0], "GMT", "M/d/yyyy");
      gigDates = gigDates + '"'+ssDate+'"'+",";
      }
    }
  }
gigDates = gigDates + "]";
 Logger.log(gigDates);
  return gigDates;
}
```

Comment: dmy I assume stands for day month year, and all of your outputted dates are in mdy, month day year.

Comment: @TylerH yes but The two dates have been formatted to match each other.  I'll add a snippet of the console output above.

Comment: They "look" indeed the same in console but are they of the same type ? does your gs function return an array of strings with quotes or just an array of strings ? did you join it ? could you show the gs function too please ?

Comment: @Sergeinsas Thats my suspicion but I don't have the experience to really tell.  See the edit above.

Comment: Not certain why you thought it should.

Comment: It seems `getDates` returns simple string, but not array, so you have what you have. you must either parse this output string to build array with strings or modify  `getDates`.

Comment: I made a test from your code but the JQuery datePicker is locked... I don't see why...apart from that, you are making a search in an array but what your GS code returns is a pure string builded with commas and quotes. I don't think the js code could be able to iterate in it but I'm definitely not an expert in client javascript in html. I'll keep searching here. @Alezis : sorry, didn't see your comment but you expressed more clearly what I meant ;-) thx

Comment: @Loren, the answer below is right, now that I get your code working I understand why the datepicker was locked... I didn't catch the idea behind the code. Interesting ! , thanks for the tip. test here : https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwGClq44tQn_T3pd4jlysJBwd9tlWcgSV3AtSIm9B3AJjmHwPVN/exec   june 24 to july 10 ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should return Array object instead of string. Your code should looks like following:

```
function getDates(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AnDrS3YbyWoLdC15aktnMTluUkQ3dWhNTFlyQXBPOFE");
  var list = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var values = list.getRange(1,5,ss.getLastRow(),5).getValues();

  var gigDates = [];


  for (var i in values){
    if (values[i][0]!=""){
      if (values[i][0] != "Gig Date"){
        var ssDate = Utilities.formatDate(values[i][0], "GMT", "M/d/yyyy");
      gigDates.push(ssDate);
      }
    }
  }

 Logger.log(gigDates);
  return gigDates;
}
```

Another option could be parse returned string with regex (`[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}`), thus your `availible` function could looks like:

```
    function available(date) {
        console.log("From the Spread sheet:  " +gigDates);
        var dmy = (date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
        console.log(dmy+' : '+($.inArray(dmy, gigDates.match(/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}/gmi))));
        if ($.inArray(dmy, gigDates) != -1) {
            return [true, "","Available"];
        } else {
            return [false,"","unAvailable"];
        }
    }
```

However, I recomend fixing `getDates` as a more properly way.